# sending hidden field value in NavigateUrl of radwindow

Tags: c#, asp.net

the code :

```
 <telerik:RadWindow ID="window_GoogleMap" runat="server" ShowContentDuringLoad="false"
        AutoSizeBehaviors="Default" Animation="Fade" OpenerElementID="btn_GoogleMap"
        AutoSize="true" Skin="Metro" Behaviors="Close,Resize,Move" VisibleStatusbar="false" OnClientBeforeShow="beforeShow"
        NavigateUrl='<%# "NetworksMap.aspx?ctry="+ hf_Country.Value +"&name="+ BasePage.GlobalCountryName+"&casa="+document.getElementById("<%=hf_Casa.ClientID %>").value +"&twn="+document.getElementById("<%=hf_Casa.ClientID %>").value %>'>
    </telerik:RadWindow>
```

I am pretty sure that the hf_Casa and the hf_Town have values but it's giving me an error that the url isn't set correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use variable values in an element attribute value like that (i.e. using `"some + variable + etc"` between the quotes), it's seen as a literal string. Instead, do it either using inline code blocks (`<%= %>` ... awful) or set it from code-behind.